# How to get element from an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an array which contain some keys and against those keys I have some elements. I want to access elements of my array in my controller in order to make graph. Please tell me how can I extract the elements as keys of array are unknown.

Comment: What have you tried, post your code samples and the error you're getting.

Comment: post you question clearly

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_values()` function

```
$a=array("Name"=>"Peter","Age"=>"41","Country"=>"USA");

print_r(array_values($a));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => Peter [1] => 41 [2] => USA )
```